# grep string from locate results

Tags: grep, sh

I'm trying to locate specific files as follow:

```
locate myfile.conf
```

Then to print all specific string that I want to find

```
locate myfile.conf | xargs cat | grep filename
```

The command returns my two lines

```
filename
filename
```

Now, How can I know what is the specific `myfile.conf` location that the "filename" found?

There is another simply way to achive what I'm need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `cat`command is useless as you use xargs

`--color` help to highlight file location

`-H` display filename and its path of match result

`-n` display the line number inside the file

```
locate myfile.conf | xargs grep --color -Hn filename
```

Answer (score 1):

my assumption is you have certain `*.conf` files which have a specific string `filename` in this case and you are looking to find those files with specific string. right ? if so

try this

```
grep -l filename `find ./ -name *.conf`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate `cat` and use `grep` only:

```
locate myfile.conf | xargs grep filename
```

Grep will prepend filename of the matched file to each output line.